# sort posts by alphabetic plugin suggestion

Tags: plugin-recommendation, query-posts, sort

I am looking for plugin to sort posts by alphabetic orders.

```
Sort: A-Z Z-A Newest Oldest
```

and 
option to view per page like in stake exchange websites

```
Per Page: 20 40 60 All
```

if not exists, can i do this in **query post**(How ?)
Please suggest me !

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know about a plugin but you can do that easily with query_posts()

paste this two functions in your theme's functions.php file

```
function display_sort_links(){
    ?>
    <div class="sort_links">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="?P_O=az">A - Z</a></li>
            <li><a href="?P_O=za">Z - A</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <?php
}

function display_posts_numbers(){
    ?>
    <div class="number_links">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="?P_P=20">20</a></li>
            <li><a href="?P_P=40">40</a></li>
            <li><a href="?P_P=60">60</a></li>
            <li><a href="?P_P=-1">All</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

then paste this in the archive file just above you loop (`if have_posts()`)

```
global $query_string;
parse_str( $query_string, $args );
//check for posts number per page
if (isset($_GET['P_P'])){
    $args['posts_per_page'] = (int)$_GET['P_P'];
}
//check for posts order a-z or z-a
if (isset($_GET['P_O'])){
    switch ($_GET['P_O'])){
        case "az":
            $args['orderby'] = 'title';
            $args['order'] = 'ASC';
            break;
        case "za":
            $args['orderby'] = 'title';
            $args['order'] = 'DESC' ;
            break;
    }
}

query_posts( $args );
```

and where ever you want the links to show just call the functions from before :

```
//for a-z z-a sort use:
<?php display_sort_links(); ?>

//and for numbers use:
<?php display_posts_numbers(); ?>
```

Comment: I want to give this a go. But i have many posts (10 thousand) and i was wondering if these queries could end up being slow and generate performance issues on busy sites?